# TypeError: gettext() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, self

I'm new to python and I'm tring to make a class for a modul which checking curses in texts.
can someone help please?

```
import urllib

class Checktext:

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def gettext(self):
        file = open(self.text, "r")
        filetext = open.read()
        for word in filetext.split():
            openurl = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=" + word)
            output = openurl.read()
            truer = "true" in str(output)
            print(truer)

s = Checktext(r"C:\Users\Tzach\.atom\Test\Training\readme.txt") 
Checktext.gettext()
```

Comment: You probably wanted `s.gettext()` not `Checktext.gettext()`. Just so you know: to include a block of code paste it as text, then select it and press the `{}` button. This will indent it by 4 spaces which is how the code blocks are made. `>` are *quote* blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You declared `s` as a new Checktext object, so you need to call `s.gettext()` not  an un-instantiated `Checktext.gettext()`, as that has no `self` to refer to

Answer (score 2):

The `urllib` is a package. You have to import the *module* `request` that is located in the package:

```
import urllib.request
```

The `open(filename)` return a file object. You want to call the method of that object:

```
filetext = file.read()
```

And as G. Anderson wrote, you want to call `s.gettext()` instead of `Checktext.gettext()`. The `self` inside is actually equal to the `s` outside. If you want to be *weird* then you actually can use also:

```
Checktext.gettext(s)
```

Notice the `s` passed as your *missing* parameter. Here Python actually reveals how the Object Oriented things are implemented internally. In majority of OO languages, it is carefully hidden, but calling a method of an object is always internally translated as passing one more special argument that points to the *instance* of the class, that is the *object*. When defining a Python method, that special argument is explicitly named `self` (by convention; you can name it differently -- you can try as the lecture, but you should *always* keep that convention).

Thinking about it thoroughly, you can get the key idea of the hidden magic of an OO language syntax. The instance of the class (the object) is actually only a portion of memory that stores the data part, and that is passed to the functions that implement the methods. The `Checktext.gettext` is actually the function, the `s` is the object. The `s.gettext()` is actually only a different way to express exactly the same. AS `s` is the instance of the `Checktext` class, the fact is stored inside the `s`. Therefore, the `s.gettext()` creates the illusion that *the rigth code will be called magically*. It fits with the trained brain better than the function approach if the `s` is thought as a *tangible something*.

Comment: Disagree on the first part of your answer. You can either `from urllib import request` and use it as `request.urlopen()`, or you can import the entire package as OP has done `import urllib` and call it as `urllib.request.urlopen()`. The second is preferable if you want to use more than one module from the package

Comment: @G. Anderson This is not disagreement. This is only another form of importing _the module_ named `request`. (And then you would have to change also the code.) On the other hand, you cannot import _a package_ only.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding what you're saying. You _can_ import the entire `urllib` package, which imports all modules it contains at once instead of one at a time. That's the only part I disagree with you about, where you say you "have to" import only the module. If I `import urllib` then call `urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com')` it works perfectly fine (`<http.client.HTTPResponse at 0x19e898fa668>`). It's just more memory efficient to only import modules you plan to use.

Comment: @G.Anderson It does not work for me. Can you show the code? What Python do you use?

Comment: I see the confusion now. I am able to run my code in jupyter notebook, but in command line ipython or in a script file it only works if I import request from urlllib. Very strange behavior!

Comment: @G.Anderson Sometimes, it could be also a case that you did import the `urllib.request` (for example) as the part of the other functionality. Then `import urllib` actually does nothing, but the right module was already imported. So, it seemingly works because of the import command that should not work.

Comment: I tried and nope, even on a brand new, fresh jupyter session and clean notebook, `import urllib` automatically pulls in `urllib.request`. Weird.